# XSLT to convert an XML to XML not giving results expected...

Tags: xslt

Is this the correct way to write this xslt ? First is the XML snippet I want to convert, second is the xslt I'm writing and finally the result:

```
<ysl:TableNodeStyle TableRenderingOrder="RowsFirst"> 
      <ysl:TableNodeStyle.Table> 
        <y:Table Insets="30,0,0,0" RelativeLocation="0,0"> 
          <y:Table.Rows

> 
                <y:Row MinimumSize="10" Size="185.389513343799" Insets="30,0,0,0" Style="{y:GraphMLReference 2}"> 
                  <y:Row.Labels> 
                    <y:Label LabelModelParameter="{x:Static ysl:StretchStripeLabelModel.West}" Style="{y:GraphMLReference 1}" PreferredSize="72,15"> 
                      <y:Label.Text>Development</y:Label.Text> 
                    </y:Label> 
                  </y:Row.Labels> 
                </y:Row>
```

Next

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:ysl="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-for-silverlight/1.0/xaml" 
> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 

    <xsl:element name="graphml"> 
      <xsl:element name="graph"> 
        <xsl:element name="TableNodeStyle"> 
          <xsl:attribute name="TableRenderingOrder"><xsl:value-of select="TableRenderingOrder"/></xsl:attribute> 

          <xsl:element name="TableNodeStyle.Table"> 
            <xsl:element name="Table"> 
            <xsl:attribute name="Table"><xsl:value-of select="Table"/></xsl:attribute> 
              <xsl:element name="Table.Rows"> 
                <xsl:element name="Row"> 
                  <xsl:attribute name="Row"><xsl:value-of select="Row"/></xsl:attribute> 
                  <xsl:element name="Label"> 
                    <xsl:attribute name="Label"><xsl:value-of select="Label"/></xsl:attribute> 
                  <!--<y:Row.Labels> 
                    <y:Label LabelModelParameter="{x:Static ysl:StretchStripeLabelModel.West}" Style="{y:GraphMLReference 1}" PreferredSize="72,15"> 
                      <y:Label.Text>Development</y:Label.Text>--> 
                  </xsl:element> 
                </xsl:element> 
              </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:element> 
          </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<graphml> 
  <graph> 
    <TableNodeStyle TableRenderingOrder=""> 
      <TableNodeStyle.Table> 
        <Table Table=""> 
          <Table.Rows> 
            <Row Row=""> 
              <Label Label="" /> 
            </Row> 
          </Table.Rows> 
        </Table> 
      </TableNodeStyle.Table> 
    </TableNodeStyle> 
  </graph> 
</graphml>
```

This is obviously not working as expected and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. ANy help would be most appreciated.

Comment: When you say "This is obviously not working as expected" could you be more specific? What exactly is not as you expect? Is it the empty Table, Row and Label attributes in the output XML?

Comment: Yes, I was expecting to see the Insets="30,0,0,0" RelativeLocation="0,0" i nthe table attributes etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the stylesheet. 
Taking a look at the TableNodeStyle output element for example, your context node for the `<xsl:value-of>` is the root of the document. You could create a new template within the stylesheet to match the `<ysl:TableNodeStyle>` element in the input document:

```
<xsl:template match="TableNodeStyle">
    <xsl:element name="TableNodeStyle">
        <xsl:attribute name="TableRenderingOrder"><xsl:value-of select="@TableRenderingOrder"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you have a template that matches the TableNodeStyle element in the source XML and can be applied with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="graphml">
        <xsl:element name="graph">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Second, your `<xsl:value-of select="TableRenderingOrder"/>` should be `<xsl:value-of select="@TableRenderingOrder"/>` - you need the @ to specify you're looking for an attribute in the `"@TableRenderingOrder"`.

You can then create a template for each child element and call those, either specifically by element or by `<xsl:call-templates/>`.

From looking at your original stylesheet I think it would be very useful for you to find some simple examples on the web and run through those before coming back to this problem. There should be enough that you can learn more about what you're trying to do here.

UPDATE:
OK, I've created what might be a useful stylesheet for you - it does what I think you're trying to do, and might be a good starting point for you, but I really recommend finding out how it works rather than just copying and hoping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:ysl="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-for-silverlight/1.0/xaml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Label">
        <xsl:element name="Label">
            <xsl:attribute name="LabelModelParameter"><xsl:value-of select="@LabelModelParameter"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Style"><xsl:value-of select="@Style"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="PreferredSize"><xsl:value-of select="@PreferredSize"/></xsl:attribute>
            <!--<y:Row.Labels> 
                <y:Label LabelModelParameter="{x:Static ysl:StretchStripeLabelModel.West}" Style="{y:GraphMLReference 1}" PreferredSize="72,15"> 
                  <y:Label.Text>Development</y:Label.Text>-->
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:element name="Row">
        <xsl:attribute name="MinimumSize"><xsl:value-of select="@MinimumSize"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Size"><xsl:value-of select="@Size"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Insets"><xsl:value-of select="@Insets"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Style"><xsl:value-of select="@Style"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table">
    <xsl:element name="Table">
        <xsl:attribute name="Insets"><xsl:value-of select="@Insets"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="RelativeLocation"><xsl:value-of select="@RelativeLocation"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="Table.Rows">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="TableNodeStyle.Table">
    <xsl:element name="TableNodeStyle.Table">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="TableNodeStyle">
    <xsl:element name="TableNodeStyle">
        <xsl:attribute name="TableRenderingOrder"><xsl:value-of select="@TableRenderingOrder"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="graphml">
        <xsl:element name="graph">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I appreciate your feedback. I'll look at my code further.

Comment: @LeeWarren - I've added a complete stylesheet that I hope gives you more to go on. Good luck with it!

Comment: THanks again Matt. I've copied the code and run it against the xml but the result is:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <graphml> <graph>
and it doesnt return anything else.

Comment: @LeeWarren - I've edited my answer - my formatting had missed the closing </xsl:stylesheet> tag, which means if you copied it straight from my reply it probably wouldn't have worked. And if you missed out the namespace declarations it wouldn't match the elements.
I have to go now - try my updated stylesheet. It's producing output for me here, so I hope that it does for you now. If I get time later, I will check back.

Comment: I had used the closing tag and ensured that the ns decalarations are included. I can't seem to post the results here as there isnt any Reply button for me to use. However, my results include the Graphml and Graph elements, but there is lots of white space going down half the page to the closing element names. If I run the mouse down over the entire page I can see the indentations of where code should be but its only whitespace. The xml document that have to format is much more complex and runs to 528 lines. I also have to ensure that a schema is attached! lol.